# How to use sequel Dataset#where{} and access a specific field for comparision?

Tags: ruby, associations, where-clause, sequel

I have three tables: fellows, mappingtabl, events with a many_to_many association in the model Fellow to access the events for a fellow.
Like always one fellow can attend multi events and many fellow make an event..

I found it is really hard to filter events without coding it myself, or I am not able to understand sequel docu:

I want a list of future events for a specific fellow...

```
@fellow=Fellow[PersID: @pers_id, JourneyID: @journey_id] 
@events=@fellow.events_dataset.where(Ruby: 'calc')
@events=@events.where{StartDate > Time.now()}
```

The thing is, the output is: uninitialized constant App::StartDate 
While 'StartDate' is the corresponding column in DB I understand the output from Ruby perspective. I never told the block what StartDate is and in addition it thinks it is a constant

How do I tell sequel to compare the Time stored in the Field events.StartDate and compare it with Time.now? 
The direct selection a line above worked perfect using a hash value pair...

The docu is not very helpful as they simple do what I did:

```
items.where{credit > debit}.sql
# "SELECT * FROM items WHERE (credit > debit)
```

Nobody told the block what credit or debit are...

Any ideas how to access the Field StartDate in events for a where clause? I can iterate an my own but this is a bit strange... it feels that it makes a difference if the dataset is directly linked to a table or just a result of an association.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the following:

```
@events=@events.where{StartDate() > Time.now()}
@events=@events.where{self.StartDate > Time.now()}
@events=@events.where{|o| o.StartDate > Time.now()}
@events=@events.where(Sequel[:StartDate] > Time.now)
```

Answer (score 0):

@events=@events.where{events[:StartDate]> Time.now()}

The key was hidden in sequels virtual row docu...